# What’s the equivalent of a repeated box-shadow?

Tags: css

The designer applied a button’s box shadow in Figma with `1rem blur-radius` multiple times, to render it stronger.

I figured out that I can approximate the same box shadow with a single one, using a smaller `blur-radius` and a `spread-radius`.

So I’m wondering: How do repeated box-shadows get combined, and how could one calculate the single shadow to replace the repetition?

```css
body {
  background: #000f4d;
}

button {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000f4d;;
  border: .1rem solid white;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
  padding: .8rem 1.3rem;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.multiple {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #0dc0f7,  0 0 1rem #0dc0f7, 0 0 1rem #0dc0f7, 0 0 1rem #0dc0f7;
}

.equivalent {
  box-shadow: 0 0 .625rem .4rem #0dc0f7;
}

.single {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem #0dc0f7;
}
```

```html
<button class="multiple">Multiple shadows</button>
<button class="equivalent">Equivalent single shadow</button>
<button class="single">Single shadow</button>
```

Comment: Maybe just add up values. Or simply tell your designer to get _real_ and make it single shadow instead?

Comment: I agree that it would be better if the designer provided one single shadow, but I’m curious how it works. What do you mean by adding up? Which values? And how would one add up colours? CSS `mix-blend-mode` defines different modes like difference or multiply.

Comment: You have to dig into the implementation of box-shadow and some math stuff, good luck.

Comment: the darkening happens because each blur averages colors between the shadow itself and the background. the weighted average of opacity is related to distance from edge probably linearly. one could start with calculating one step. then apply it n times to make some sort of a curve that will eventually be black but faster on the inner side. is it possible to do using a single box-shadow? well it won't be the same linear "easing" so you'll need to break it down to a multistep gradient which i'm not sure it's possible in box shadow. so no.

Comment: Oh that’s interesting. So the resulting gradient would not be linear, hence it’s not even possible. I didn’t consider that.